# Which software and tools i should use to create software presentation like this one?

Tags: presentations

I want to create a screen captured audio (microphone) - video presentation of my software. So i'm looking for best screencasting softwares out there which should allow me to edit recorded audio and video as well as adjust audio.. fast-forward specific portion of video.. zoom in and out specific portions in real-time without loosing quality as well as few cool effects on software window.
Please check following 3 videos :

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zmOYziFKZw
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0QXB5pw2qE
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mk-O22wu-kc

From those videos, i'm looking for following features :
- I would like to have text typing effect.
- The browser window is tilted a little when typing to give really cool 3d like effect.
- Zooming of specific potions really look cool in real-time without loosing any graphic quality.

Please suggest me softwares and tools i can use to create similar video presentation. It doesn't matter even if the software and tools are commercial/paid products.

Comment: The primary difference between screen recording apps is to what extent one can add their own presentation overlays (call outs, cursors, dialogs, alerts, labels, etc.) and how easy/flexible doing so is, so I'd argue it is on-topic for graphic design.

Answer (score 0):

[Camstasia Studio 7](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/) is awesome! Easy to use and intuitive!